# Preview Laravel Mail before sending

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to edit my mail and change everything, if I want, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724118/laravel-5-4-how-to-customize-notification-email-layout).

Ive imported my file and created a test route to view the page:

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Markdown;

Route::get('/mail/html', function () {
    $markdown = new Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown'));
    return $markdown->render('vendor.mail.html.message'); // or ..markdown.message
});
```

However, Im having variable errors for `@slot`. How to view my change/see what the mail looks like before sending? Another package for that?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, all. I'll confirm tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the recommended way by the Laravel community**

kunal has a nice quick solution and that's how I used to do it. But now I use mailtrap.io to test emails because it allows you to replicate the whole process of sending an email.

1. Create a (**free**) account with [mailtrap.io](http://mailtrap.io).
2. Add your mailtrap username and password in `.env` file.

By the way, Laravel is already configured to use mailtrap by default, so it is their recommended way to test emails.

Watch how Jeffrey Ways does it in his lesson:
**Laravel 5.4 From Scratch: Sending Email**

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/26

Comment: Yes, sorry. Mail trap was the way forward

Answer (score 5):

To preview your email in browser please add below code to route

```
Route::get('preview-notification', function () {
 $markdown = new \Illuminate\Mail\Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown'));   
 $data = "Your data to be use in blade file";
 return $markdown->render("path-of-your-templete-blade-file", $data]);
});
```

and you will be access your templete using

```
http://your-application-url/preview-notification
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to test in locally. You can put echo command in blade file at end and put **die;** this way you can test.Suppose you have test-email.blade.php

```
test-email.blade.php // file name
This is tets mail
<?php echo "test"; die; ?>
```

Hope it helps!