# Laravel 5.4 mail messages how to edit header and footer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hi I am trying to use MailMessage function in my Laravel App. My question is very simple. How to edit the Header and the Footer when receiving email from the app? Here is the picture below.

[image]

I want to change the header Laravel from my App name and the Hello with a Hello $user->name and the Regards, with my App name also and the footer below to the App name also.

[image]

I tried to change the `

> resources/views/vendor/mail/markdown/message.blade.php

To:

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            CCTV App
        @endcomponent
    @endslot

    {{-- Body --}}
    {{ $slot }}

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @isset($subcopy)
        @slot('subcopy')
            @component('mail::subcopy')
                CCTV Team
            @endcomponent
        @endslot
    @endisset

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            © {{ date('Y') }} CCV3. All rights reserved.
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

But not working when I send a reset password request
Would really appreciate if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 - How to customize notification email layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724118/laravel-5-4-how-to-customize-notification-email-layout)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I want to change the header Laravel from my App name and the Hello with a Hello $user->name and the Regards, with my App name also and the footer below to the App name also

Mailable Markdown by default has the `config('app.name')` that picks the `APP_NAME` from your .env file. So by modifying the `APP_NAME` will effect on your markdown template.

OR if you modifying it manually, run the following command on your terminal
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail` and go to the `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php` and modify the header and footer slot.

For changing Hello to **Hello {user_name}**, there is markdown called [greeting()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#mail-notifications) method that holds `Hello!`, you can change it whatever you want.

For **Regards** run this command on your terminal
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications` and go to the `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php` and modify the **Regards** whatever you want.

To know more in details take a look on [customizing markdown email](https://webomnizz.com/laravel-notification-customize-markdown-email-header-and-footer/).

Comment: This was way more useful. Big help to others out there.

Answer (score 5):

I already figure it out just change the name of the env file to your App name instead of laravel. This is the sample below.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
```

Change it to

```
APP_NAME=YOUR_APP_NAME
```

there is also one way to edit your mail template.
Just go to **resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php**
and you can also edit the message to your mail just go to **resources/views/vendor/markdown/message.blade.php**

Answer (score 1):

You are using default component for your email template named `@component('mail::message')`, It does not allow you to modify header. But if you go to the file of this component,

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\resources\views\markdown\message.blade.php
```

you will notice that it uses another component `@component('mail::layout')`,

Just copy content of `message.blade.php` file into your `.blade.php` and replace `{{ $slot }}` with what you had in your file before.

And you are done.