# How can I solve "No hint path defined for [mail]." (customize email layout) on laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, notifications, laravel-5.4

From here : [Laravel 5.4 - How to customize notification email layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724118/laravel-5-4-how-to-customize-notification-email-layout)

I try customize notification email layout

My code to send email like this :

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Test')
                ->view('vendor.mail.markdown.message',['data'=>$this->data]);
}
```

The view like this :

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            {{ config('app.name') }}
        @endcomponent
    @endslot

    {{-- Body --}}
    {{ $slot }} test

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @isset($subcopy)
        @slot('subcopy')
            @component('mail::subcopy')
                {{ $subcopy }}
            @endcomponent
        @endslot
    @endisset

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            © {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. All rights reserved.
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

If the code executed, there exist error like this :

> (2/2) ErrorException No hint path defined for [mail]. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\resources\views\vendor\mail\markdown\message.blade.php)

How can I solve the error?

Comment: try this command to publish mail directory from package to your views php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail

Comment: @umefarooq, I have done that. But it's the same

Answer (score 24):

If you are using markdown in your template, you need to use the `->markdown()` method rather than the `->view()` method on your `MailMessage`

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Test')
            ->markdown('vendor.mail.markdown.message', ['data' => $this->data]);
}
```

Comment: Same problem as OP, I'm not using markdown but this solved the problem.

Comment: If dont want to use pre-shiped  markdown then whats the solution

Answer (score 1):

In the recent version of Laravel, the trick happen in the `content()` method:

```php
// change from :
return new Content(
    view: 'view.name', // ❌Nope     
);

// To :
return new Content( 
    markdown: 'view.name', // Yup 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In an application migrated through different Laravel versions (and now at 5.6) I had to modify the file `config/mail.php`, changing the parameter `markdown/paths` from `resource_path('views/vendor/mail')` to `resource_path('views/vendor/mail/markdown')`, so it found the base templates for my Markdown mails.