# How do you customize variables in Laravel default emails?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-mail

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42725231/2031033) to publish the default email templates in my application with:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

This works great, but clearly there is some configuration options, such as:

```
{{-- Greeting --}}
@if (! empty($greeting))
# {{ $greeting }}
@else
@if ($level === 'error')
# @lang('Whoops!')
@else
# @lang('Hello!')
@endif
@endif

{{-- Salutation --}}
@if (! empty($salutation))
{{ $salutation }}
@else
@lang('Regards'),<br>{{ config('app.name') }}
@endif
```

Right now my emails are sending "Hello!" and "Regards" from the else section but clearly there is a way to set these defaults for email templates using variables. How do I set the `$greeting` and `$salutation` variables when sending emails?

Comment: I'm trying to find where the definition for `@lang('Regards')` is stored. It isn't exposed in my code base currently. It may be helpful if anyone can add that info as a comment or additional answer here. I found this question by Googling `@lang('Regards')` with double-quotes around it.

I'd like to add something like `@lang('Team')` adjacent to the Regards definition.

Comment: But it's worth noting that `resources/lang` is a folder location, and a person may be able to add any customizations there. I just haven't learned enough about that yet to say how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template you posted is the default template for [notification mails](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#markdown-mail-notifications).
When creating such notification with for example:

`php artisan make:notification InvoicePaid --markdown=mail.invoice.paid`

A new InvoicePaid class is created at `app/Notifications/InvoicePaid.php`.
This class contains a `toMail()` method with the following contents:

`return (new MailMessage)->markdown('mail.invoice.paid');`

The `MailMessage` class extends the `SimpleMessage` class.
The `SimpleMessage` class has the methods `greeting()` and `salutation()`  which you can use to set the greeting or salutation.

For example:

```
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
           ->greeting("Your custom greeting")
           ->salutation("Your salutation goes here")
           ->markdown('mail.invoice.paid');
}
```

Comment: Okay very helpful! I'm looking to overwrite the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` template. So I'm guessing I should overwrite that method in **app/User.php** and create a new mailable with that markdown flag. I'll probably copy some of the functionality from `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail`

Comment: Yes, just overwrite the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` method in your User model and you should be good.