# Laravel 5.4 vendor publish component not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm attempting to modify the template for e-mails on an older website I did, running Laravel 5.4

I do eventually plan to update to at least Laravel 5.5, and possibly Laravel 5.7 - but I don't want to do that right now unless strictly necessary (it would involve some significant re-writes to some of my controllers and a ***lot*** of extra testing)

I ran:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

This created files in `resources/views/vendor/mail`

I then edited these files and tried sending a message. No change.

I then edited the files in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/` and sent a message - the new template showed up.

So despite the existence of the `resources/views/vendor/mail` folder, Laravel is still reading from the `vendor/` folder after running `php artisan vendor:publish`. How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

### Update

Some additional info, in case it helps. Here's my mail template (`resources/views/mail/email-a-friend.blade.php`):

```
@component('mail::message')

Your friend, {{ $senderName }}, has sent you information about a property they feel you might be interested in.


This property is listed by {{ config('app.name') }}. To view this property and more like it, please click the link below.


@if($agent->id !== $property->agent->id)
[{{ url($property->url()) }}?agent={{ $agent->first_name }}-{{ $agent->last_name }}]({{ url($property->url()) }}?agent={{ $agent->first_name }}-{{ $agent->last_name }})
@else
[{{ url($property->url()) }}]({{ url($property->url()) }})
@endif
@if($text != "")


They also sent this message:


@component('mail::panel')
{{ $text }}
@endcomponent
@endif
@endcomponent
```

Here's the controller that queues up the e-mail (`app/http/Controllers/AjaxController.php` - just the relevant function):

```
public function emailAFriend(Request $request)
{
    $property = \App\Models\Property\Property::find($request->input('property-id'));
    $agent = $property->agent;
    if ($request->input('agent-id') !== $agent->id) {
        $agent = \App\User::find($request->input('agent-id'));
    }

    Mail::to($request->input('send-to'))
        ->queue(new \App\Mail\EmailAFriend($property, $agent, $request->input('name'), $request->input('reply-to'), $request->input('text')));

    return Response::json("success", 200);
}
```

Here's the Mailable (`app/Mail/EmailAFriend.php`):

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Models\Property\Property;
use App\User;

class EmailAFriend extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject = "Someone sent you a property!";

    public $property;
    public $agent;
    public $senderName;
    public $senderEmail;
    public $text;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Property $property, User $agent, $name, $email, $text)
    {
        $this->subject = "$name sent you information about a property";

        $this->property = $property;
        $this->agent = $agent;
        $this->senderName = $name;
        $this->senderEmail = $email;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.email-a-friend')
                    ->replyTo($this->senderEmail, $this->senderName)
                    ->attachData(
                        $this->property->generatePdf(['agent' => $this->agent])->inline(),
                        "{$this->property->details->lot_size} acres in {$this->property->location->county} county.pdf",
                        [
                            'mime' => 'application/pdf'
                        ]
                    );
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I'm using the `sync` QueueDriver, so this sends immediately upon the AJAX request being made. In production I use the `database` QueueDriver.

### Update 2

The components:

`resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php`:

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            <img src="{{ url('/img/layout/logo.png') }}" alt="{{ config('app.name') }}" />
        @endcomponent
    @endslot

    {{-- Body --}}
    {{ $slot }}

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @if (isset($subcopy))
        @slot('subcopy')
            @component('mail::subcopy')
                {{ $subcopy }}
            @endcomponent
        @endslot
    @endif

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            &copy; {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. All rights reserved.
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

`resources/views/vendor/mail/markdown/message.blade.php`:

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            ![{{ config('app.name') }}]({{ url('/img/layout/logo.png') }})
        @endcomponent
    @endslot

    {{-- Body --}}
    {{ $slot }}

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @if (isset($subcopy))
        @slot('subcopy')
            @component('mail::subcopy')
                {{ $subcopy }}
            @endcomponent
        @endslot
    @endif

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            © {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. All rights reserved.
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

The difference between these two and the default components (`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/html/message.blade.php` and the markdown equivalent) is in the header:

```
{{ config('app.name') }}
replaced with:
<img src="{{ url('/img/layout/logo.png') }}" alt="{{ config('app.name') }}" />
```

I was attempting to replace the company name with their logo. When I go into `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/markdown/message.blade.php` and edit this file directly, I ***do*** see the logo in the resulting e-mail. So despite the existence of the published component, it's still reading from the `vendor/` directory (and editing the `vendor/` directory is no good, because then the change won't persist in production)

Comment: I woul start with very basic check to empty view cache, can you try `php artisan view:clear`?

Comment: Also when you say you customized the components, did you update both markdown and html?

Comment: @MihirBhende Was hoping this would be the simple fix that did it, but no such luck. It's still reading from the `vendor` directory instead of the `resources/views/vendor` directory. And yes, I did customize both the HTML and markdown components. I'll append those to my post.

Comment: Do you have any modifications in `config/mail.php`?

Comment: @MihirBhende I've made no changes to `config/mail.php`. In fact, most of `config/mail.php` is ignored as I'm using `.env` to overwrite `MAIL_DRIVER`, `MAIL_HOST`, `MAIL_PORT`, `MAIL_USERNAME`, `MAIL_PASSWORD`, `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`, `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`, and `MAIL_FROM_NAME`.

Comment: Aha, I was checking if there are any customizations for email markdown path in the config.

Comment: Are there permission issues for the new template files?

Comment: @MihirBhende I don't think there should be permission issues, but how would I check? What permissions should the template files have? The owner is the same as every other file on my system ("ubuntu:ubuntu") and all of the directories are `drwxr-xr-x`. The files are `-rw-r--r--`.

Comment: Can you check and compare the permission and owner with the working blade files?

Comment: @MihirBhende The files in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/markdown` have the same permissions (`-rw-r--r--`). I also took a look at all of the ***other*** blade files I had (like `resources/views/emails/email-a-friend.blade.php`) and they're the same, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging through the Laravel source for over an hour, I finally figured this out.

1. The Markdown renderer loads components from its `componentPaths` variable
2. The `componentPaths` variable gets set by `loadComponentFrom()`
3. `loadComponentsFrom` is called in the constructor of the Markdown renderer and passed `$options['paths']`

Knowing this I started looking into "Laravel markdown options paths" and found the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44264874/436976

I updated `config/mail.php` and added the recommended lines and it worked perfectly! I feel like `vendor:publish` should have done this for me, or there should have at least been some mention of this step in the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#customizing-the-components), but fortunately I figured this out in under a day - so that's always nice

### Note (Further Research)

It turns out this ***was*** mentioned in the official Laravel documentation, just not where I expected.

My website was originally a Laravel 5.1 site that was upgraded to 5.2, then to 5.3, and then ultimately to 5.4 before it went live (I never updated to 5.5 because once the site was live I wanted to minimize changes to the underlying framework)

With each Laravel upgrade I kept rolling forward the old files from the `config/` directory and I apparently did a poor job of following the upgrade guides, because they are pretty clear:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

> #### New Configuration Options
>
> In order to provide support for Laravel 5.4's new Markdown mail components, you should add the following block of configuration to the bottom of your mail configuration file:

```
'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
```

Had I updated my configuration file as directed, I would never have had these issues.